# Cannot cast [B to java.util.UUID after Hibernate 6 migration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

After migrating to springboot 3.1.2, fetch results from database leads to Cannot cast [B to java.util.UUID

The postgresql column is defined as "bytea" datatype, and mapped to java.util.UUID

Entity class:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "SAMPLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
@Getter @Setter private UUID id;
```

I have tried few things but no luck:

1. As per migration notes https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#_uuid_mapping_changes I have added hibernate.type.preferred_duration_jdbc_type=BINARY
2. Define UUID converter

   ```
   @Converter(autoApply = true)
   public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {

   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final UUID entityValue) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(entityValue)
               .map(entityUuid -> entityUuid.toString())
               .orElse(null);
   }

   @Override
   public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(final String databaseValue) {
       return Optional.ofNullable(databaseValue)
               .map(databaseUuid -> UUID.fromString(databaseUuid))
               .orElse(null);
   }
   ```
3. Using @JdbcType(UUIDJdbcType.class) on entity's attribute

   ```
   @Id
   @JdbcType(UUIDJdbcType.class)
   @Column(name = "SAMPLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
   @Getter @Setter private UUID id;
   ```

Not sure if this is a hibernate or spring data problem, anyone migrated to hibernate6 faced this issue?